# Query openstreetmap data layer for use with R ggplot + sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, r-sf

I'm trying to figure out how to re-plot the vector data from openstreetmaps using `sf` and `ggplot2`. I know I can get a raster background using `ggmap`, but I'm hoping I can get a much higher quality plot by using the underlying vector data directly.

Here is some code that get's me some site data.

```
map <- get_map(location = bb, maptype = "toner", source = "stamen", zoom = 15)
ggmap(map)
```

This produces:

[image: generic ggmap site]

Of course, I would like to get the same result using vector graphics. Here is a Overpass query that selects data from the same bounding box as above.

```
[out:xml][timeout:60];
(
  node(38.0151865284475, -121.872227331133, 38.0340023660995, 121.829405993985);
  <;
  >;
);
out body;
```

Plugging that into the [overpass API](https://overpass-turbo.eu/#) seems to highlight a lot of data, but when I plot in R I see some weird looking stuff.

```
library(osmdata)
q <- "[out:xml][timeout:60];\n  (\n  node(38.0151865284475, -121.872227331133, 38.0340023660995, -121.829405993985);\n      <;\n      >;\n  );\n  out body;\n  "
r <- osmdata_sf(q)
plot(r[["osm_multipolygons"]]["osm_id"])
```

[image: OSM query results]

I'm aiming to plot something that looks much like the original openstreetmap plotting view, but which only includes railroads, streets, bodies of water, buildings and wetlands. So, I need to figure out how to download everything that is contained within or touches the bounding box. Maybe nodes by itself can't get this information? Can I actually do what I want to `osmdata` or should I take a different approach?

Comment: try [osmdata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmdata/index.html) together with [osmplotr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmplotr/index.html)

Comment: @TimSalabim could you provide an example? Reading the documentation of both packages (as well as their update timelines), it appears to me that `osmdata` is a successor to `osmplotr`.

Comment: there are plenty of examples on the [github page](https://github.com/ropensci/osmplotr)